# Angular.js multiple rest calls scope issue

Tags: javascript, angularjs, rest

i'm a biginner when it comes to Angular.js, and i have a problem with $scope not getting additional value from one of two $resource rest calls. Here's my code:

```
controller: function ($scope, $modalInstance, $route) {
            $scope.server = {}

            $scope.submit = function () {
                //AddNewServer is a $resource service
                AddNewServer.post($.param({
                    'name': $scope.server.name,
                    'ip': $scope.server.ip,
                    'port': $scope.server.port
                }));

                //ServerStats is a $resource service
                ServerStats.postServerStats(function success(data) {
                    $scope.server.bytesIn = data.returnValue.bytesIn
                }, function err(err) {
                    console.log("Error: " + err)
                })

                $modalInstance.dismiss('cancel');
                $route.reload()

                //BELLOW LOG RETURNS Object {name: "asd", ip: "asd", port: 2} NO bytesIn
                console.log($scope.server) 
            }

            $scope.cancel = function () {
                $modalInstance.dismiss('cancel');
                $route.reload()
            };
        }
```

Question is how do i add bytesIn from my other service call into my server object? I'm sure it a pretty obvious thing but i'm still in learning phase. Thanks in advance.

Comment: don't forget to mark an answer as correct if it helped you!

Answer (score 1):

Your postServerStats() call is asynchronous, so it's likely that your success function isn't being called before the console.log($scope.server) statement.

Put console.log($scope.server) in your success function, after you assign $scope.server.bytesIn.

Perhaps you mean to do more work in your postServerStats() callback?

Or better yet, look into [angular promises](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24q)

Comment: Thanks for reply! I added console.log($scope.server) in my success callback and it is giving me object that i want: {name: "asd", ip: "asd", port: 2, bytesIn: 7076}. Whan i want to do is to be able to use that $scope.server on my page to show data, but i get only first 3 parameters (name, ip, port) and not bytesIn if i use it in lets say div with ng-repeat.